# Facebook All Mutual Friends API Feature Review Requirements

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

I'm using Facebook All mutual friends API to return number of all mutual friends (app-using and non-app-using) between a user and another one that is their friend.

However the All Mutual Friends API feature review requirements are very unclear and it looks like instructions are conflicting.

I have asked them in Facebook direct support and havent gotten a response in more than a week.

Here is feature review instructions:
[image: Feature review]

This is app review instructions:
[image: App review]

Does that mean the crosses next to common usage is allowed? But why are there crosses on the instructions whereas the ticked common usage is not even shown on app review

By the way this isn't asking for mutual friends permission, that doesnt need asking as its all users who use the app already.

Comment: The X are not allowed. The app review instructions asks if you are doing that.

Comment: So do I tick other on app review instructions to write down my use case? Apologies, I dont want to not pass the review.

Comment: You check the options for the thing you do.

Comment: ok so it doesnt do any of those on the app review, so im guessing i submit as other?

Comment: Your app does not do any of those three things? What does it use the permission for?

Comment: Its the first use case ticked: Display social context between the person using your app and another app user

Comment: Then check that box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this appears for you, Wizkid above has answered for me.

Basically tick the OTHER box and then fill in your selection as based on the allowed use cases. Facebook is pretty quick to review and will generally get back to you within one business day.